# How to split lines but keep those with tabs?

Tags: c#, split

I know how to split a long string by new lines

```
string[] lines = d.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine },
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

But I would like to

```
Split in new lines like this
and in new lines + tabs
    like this, in order to have
    an array which contains the first line and this second block.
```

Basically I would like to split not by one rule, but by two.
The resulting array should contain following strings:

```
[0] Split in new lines like this
[1] and in new lines + tabs
    like this, in order to have
    an array which contains the first line and this second block.
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Define specific rules (And then you could probably answer your own question)

Comment: Post large sample of data.  I've been parsing text files for over 40 years and can help, but need larger sample of the input.

Comment: @jdweng - You don't need samples, you need rules

Comment: so `a\r\nb\r\n\tc1\r\n\tc2\r\nd` becomes `{"a","b","\tc1\r\n\tc2","d"}`?

Comment: Sorry guys. I extended my question now.

Comment: @Amit Rather speed race. Regex loses. Don't overkill simple tasks with Regex, it's bad for you.

Comment: As I said, I've been parsing text for over 40 years.  You need actual sample of the input text to get it correct the 1st time.  Most people don't understand the complexity of parsing text and following people rules NEVER NEVER NEVER work the first time.  Only an experienced parser understands how to do it correctly.

Comment: @YoryeNathan I had to leave and had no time to answer, but Alexander Petrov did. Regex wins. It's short (less code - less bugs), its clean, it requires less memory (and from that - less allocations & and less GC), its fast (no 2nd phase loop). You should use the right tool for a job, and regex is a powerful tool.

Comment: @jdweng a large sample is inappropriate for SO. It's inappropriate for a spec. It's appropriate as a validation phase, maybe an initial source for rules. Rules are appropriate for describing intentions. They're good for creating a spec for producers & consumers to understand each other and know what to expect. They're the way the world of software engineering works. The fact that in 40 years you never had a good set of rules to work with is surprising and unfortunate

Comment: Had plenty of good rules and even with good rules still required a few tweaks to get code working.  I've always take lots of tries with inputs like what the user provided in this posting.  I don't like rewriting my code 5 to 10 times because user didn't describe the inputs properly.  I lot to have proper inputs so I get it right the 1st time.

Answer (score 4):

This trick should work. I have replaced **"\n\t"** with **"\r"** temporarily. After splitting the string, restored back the **"\n\t"** string. So your array **lines**, will have desired count of strings.

This way, you can get your desired output:

```
d = d.Replace("\n\t", "\r");

string[] lines = d.Split(new string[] {"\n"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

lines = lines.Select((line) => line = line.Replace("\r", "\n\t")).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

What is a tab?
If it is 4 spaces, use the following pattern:

```
string pattern = Environment.NewLine + @"(?!\s{4})";
```

If it is tabulation, use the following pattern:

```
string pattern = Environment.NewLine + @"(?!\t)";
```

Next, we use a regular expression:

```
string[] lines = Regex.Split(text, pattern);
```

Comment: This is the most accurate solution. It's clean, short, effective and efficient

Comment: But it only splits at tabs. Not in new lines AND in tabs.

Answer (score 1):

One should use the right tool for the right situation. To avoid using a tool available to one (a tool which is in every programming language btw) is foolish.

Regex is best when a discernible pattern has to be expressed which can't be done, or easily done, by the string functions. Below I use each tool in the situation it was best designed for...

---

The following is a three stage operation using regex, string op, and Linq.

1. Identifying which lines have to be kept together due to the indented rule. This is done to not lose them in the main split operation, the operation will replace `\r\n\t` with a pipe character (`|`) to identify their specialty. This is done with regex because we are able to effectively group and process the operations with minimal overhead.
2. We split all the remaining lines by the newline character which gives us a glimpse at the final array of lines wanted.
3. We project (change) each line via linq's `Select` to change the `|` to a `\r\n`.

### Code

```
Regex.Replace(text, "\r\n\t", "|\t")
     .Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None )
     .Select (rLine => rLine.Replace("|", Environment.NewLine));
```

Try it here ([.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bmPiRp))

---

Full code with before and after results as run in LinqPad. *Note that `.Dump()` is only available in Linqpad to show results and is not a Linq extension.*

Result first:

[image]

Full code

```
string text = string.Format("{1}{0}{2}{0}\t\t{3}{0}\t\t{4}",
Environment.NewLine,
 "Split in new lines like this",
 "and in new lines + tabs",
 "like this, in order to have",
 "an array which contains the first line and this second block.");

text.Dump("Before");

var result = Regex.Replace(text, "\r\n\t", "|\t")
                  .Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None )
                  .Select (rLine => rLine.Replace("|", Environment.NewLine));

result.Dump("after");
```

Answer (score 0):

After you split all lines, you can just "join" tabbed lines like so:

```
List<string> lines = d.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine })
                      .ToList();

// loop through all lines, but skip the first (lets assume it isn't tabbed)
for (int i = 1; i < lines.Count; i++)
{
    if (lines[i][0] == '\t') // current line starts with tab
    {
        lines[i - 1] += "\r\n" + lines[i]; // append it to prev line
        lines.RemoveAt(i); // remove current line from list
        i--; // and dec i so you don't skip an item
    }
}
```

You could add more complex logic to consider different number of tabs if you wanted, but this should get you started.

If you expect many tabbed lines to be grouped together, you might want to use `StringBuilder` instead of `string` for increased performance in appending the lines back together.